# Adding trusted root certificates to the server cent os

Tags: linux, centos

I m trying to install a root certificate in my cent OS box. I did the following

1. Enable the dynamic CA configuration feature: 
   update-ca-trust force-enable
2. Add it as a new file to /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/ cp foo.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
3. Use command: update-ca-trust extract
   Then I m running below command to verify the certificate.

openssl s_client -connect my_AD_server_IP:636 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs

Bur getting below error(This is part of the error)

Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)

Answer (score 2):

Did you confirm that your cert made it into the */etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt* file?

The certs are transformed before they make it into that file, so you can't just look for a string that matches your cert.

Here's a quick awk script to dump the subject fields from each cert in that certificate file so you can look for yours:

```
awk -v cmd='openssl x509 -noout -subject' \
       '/BEGIN/{close(cmd)};{print | cmd}' \
< /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

(I found that awk script [here](https://gist.github.com/robglas/3ef9582c6292470a1743))